# django authenticate returning Nonetype with valid credentials

Tags: python, django

I have a custom user model based off of AbstractUser and, I use a custom UserManager, I don't know if theres anything special I have to do to get authenticate to work. I know the user is in the db because I can do objects.get(username, password) and it will return the object.

```
class PassThroughFarmerManager(PassThroughManagerMixin, UserManager):
        use_in_migrations = False

class Farmer(FarmStateble, MapPointable, LastRequestStorable, AbstractUser):
        last_irrigation_cycle = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null = True, blank=True)
        objects = PassThroughFarmerManager.for_queryset_class(FarmerQuerySet)()
```

Here is an example of my console output,

```
>>> models.Farmer.objects.get(username='901e2ac5-9324-11e5-81bf-c42c0323e33a').password
u'1223'
>>> u = authenticate(username = '901e2ac5-9324-11e5-81bf-c42c0323e33a', password = '1223')
>>> u
>>> type(u)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Are you hashing the password correctly when you create the user, e.g. by calling `user.set_password('new password')`? If you fetch the user with `get()`, what does it show? If it shows the unencrypted password, e.g. '1223', then you are doing it incorrectly.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm creating the user via objects.create(username, password), I'll have to try out what you said after I come home from work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `MyUserModel.objects.create(...)`, the password is stored in the database in plain text. The call to `authenticate` does not work, because Django expects the password to be hashed in the database.

Therefore, when you create a user, you need to ensure that the password is hashed, rather than being stored in plain text in the database. You can do this by calling `user.set_password('new_password')`.

The [full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) in the docs shows a `create_user` manager method that calls `set_password` when creating the user. You would then use `MyUserModel.objects.create_user(...)` instead of `MyUserModel.objects.create(...)`.

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```